# I need to get every 4 elements from String[] array and iterate through them

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with strings (answers) and get every 4 elements, and assign them to 4 radio buttons. Since I'm an inexperienced programmer, I just can't get it to work.

```
void set() // rework with array
{
    try {
        //sets the question label
        jb[4].setSelected(true);

        if (current < questions.length) {
            label.setText("Question " + (current + 1) + ": " + questions[current]);

            for (int j = current; j < (current * 4); j++) {

                // k goes through 0, 1 ,2 ,3 needed for the radio buttons
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) { // was (i+3)
                    System.out.println("Cur= " + current + " * 4= " + (current * 4) + " J= " + j + " K= " + k);

                    //System.out.println(" J= " + j + " K= " + k);
                    jb[k].setText(answers[j] + " @ " + j);

                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= 90; i += 30, j++) {
            jb[j].setBounds(50, 80 + i, 600, 20);
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error at: " + count + ex.getMessage()); //testing what's going on
    }
}
```

But on the first run (question 1) I don't get any answers set to the radio buttons, and on every other question I get the 3rd, 7th, 11th and so on answer from the array assigned to all of the radio buttons. Can't fit the console output into a code block by some reason...

Comment: What issue are you having? Show us some data, the results you're getting, and the expected results you are wanting.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting used to this site. On the first run i get no answers set to the fields and every other I get the 3rd, 7th, 11th and so on answers on every radio button.

Comment: @klincharov Please (1) [edit] your results into your post and make it clear what's wrong with them ("can't get [your] head around this problem" doesn't really help us find your issue), (2) explain what problem the code you've written is trying to solve in the first place and (3) post an [(minimal) complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find bellow the solution. But it is written very complicated and you should get it more simple.

```
void set() // rework with array
{
try {
    //sets the question label
    jb[4].setSelected(true);

    if (current < questions.length) {
        label.setText("Question " + (current + 1) + ": " + questions[current]);

        int j = current*4;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {

                jb[k].setText(answers[j+k]);

            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= 90; i += 30, j++) {
        jb[j].setBounds(50, 80 + i, 600, 20);
    }

} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error at: " + count + ex.getMessage()); //testing what's going on
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted to do !

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use modulo:

```
if(x%4 == 0) {
    //your instructions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not proposing any changes in your existing design because data structure you have followed is itself complicated.

Your application requirement can be satisfied by following simple data structure:

Have below data structure to store questions and their corresponding answers (let's say there are 10 questions).

```
// Represent map where key is question and value is list of 4 options.
Map<String, List<String>> questions = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(10);
```

have data structure to maintain list of four answers which will act as value in above data structure.

```
// Represent list of four answers.
List<String> answers = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(4);
```

Iterate over question map to get expected result.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : questions.entrySet()) {
    // Print question.
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    for (String answer : entry.getValue()) {
        // Print four options for question.
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask doubts, if you found this as confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I also came to the conclusion, that a new data structure would be more appropriate, but that's the thing i wanted to avoid from the beginning. And now I am pressured by time and work and really want to finish it with arrays before the week's end. Thank you again!